# facebook fanbage id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i get the face book user id who create face book page,now i need to get page id to display like box in my website.

different users have there own face book pages.however i know to get there facebook user id

is there any solution or alternative solution,something like fquery or etc???

Answer (score 0):

Facebook calls this a "connection". You can find a list of all available connections at the [Graph API documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api). Fan pages are not among them. You can, however, get a list of groups or events the user is involved with.

Comment: need to try atleast using fan page name to get id,but there is bit confusing title of the page and page name in the url is different

Comment: @ FRKT i need to get fan page id of user created page not user involved or user is a fan

Comment: @kasun: You can't get the ids of fan pages the user created. The Facebook API does not support it.

Comment: i have try to do this,there is no way to get fan page id via creater id,
at the end i get id from the user who likes the page,(creater also need to likea that page)